# Electric field of axially magnetized rotating disk

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Would I be able to detect E field around magnet spinning on its axis using electroscope?
I like to use electronic electroscope in setup like this:

[image: experiment]

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? The apparatus seems simple enough.

Comment: not so easy , magnet has to spin perfectly, no wobbling and orbiting, cant move in space other way than just spinning.But there should be E field or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question is equivalent to asking whether there is B field when you have a rotating electret. Which is equivalent to two rotating surface current density. And the answer is yes, there is B field in the radial and axial direction when the thickness of the electret has a finite thickness. But for an ideal electret of zero thickness there will be no B field.

So I think for a real magnet with finite thickness, there will be E field in the radial and axial direction. But when thickness of the magnet is very small, the E field vanishes.

Comment: yeah, any proof for that? book or something...

Comment: I just tried to google "rotating magnet" and found something, for example, this: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/what-is-the-electric-field-generated-by-a-spinning-magnet

Comment: I have seen that, a lot of talk but no links for real experiments...also,  where is earth electric field?, earth has magnet inside and rotates.

Comment: I think there is such an E field, but so small in magnitude because of the small $\omega$ of the Earth.